# Comma separated combination of LTR/RTL/Digit characters reorder issue

Tags: excel, unicode, right-to-left

I have a comma separated list of values generated from an excel sheet. (Numbers and RTL Characters)
Having these values in columns: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
would yield me the output of 1,2,3,4,5

But the issue arises when I have RTL characters (Persian/Arabic) in my columns: 1 2 ب الف and a 5 in the end.
Now the output becomes 1,2الف, ب, 5
Since my columns can have multiple sets of RTL characters it can really mess up the output to the point that it's no more trivial to fix it by substituting several inputs.

What are my options to produce a csv file with the right order?

Tools I used where javascript and excel and both had the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your purpose is to only display the CSV for human eye, you can add ‏RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK (&#x200F;) before each number:

```
&#x200F;1, &#x200F;2, &#x0628;, &#x0627;&#x0644;&#x0641;, &#x200F;5
```

> ‏1, ‏2, ب, الف, ‏5

Note that these characters may drive crazy any tool you use to parse the CSV.

Comment: Unfortunately this csv output has to be processed by another 3rd party application.

Comment: can't you filter out the RLM character on the pipeline to 3rd party app?

Answer (score 0):

I think your CSV file already has the right order.  In the text you pasted in the question:

> 1,2الف, ب, 5

The "1" is the first character in the string, and the "5" is the last.  It just doesn't seem that way to you because the first half of the string (1,2) is rendering LTR whereas the second half of the string (الف, ب, 5) is rendering RTL.